# Is there any security issue if server do not filter JSONP's callback parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

Say I have a JSONP api which using like this(and this is hosted on my server):

```
http://www.example.com/jsonp.php?callback=fun
```

and the server never do any security check of the callback's value which in this case is 'fun'.
It will output the callback's value as is, input what, output what.
That is:

```
http://www.example.com/jsonp.php?callback=alert();fun
```

will output something like this:

```
alert();fun({/*data goes here*/});
```

And in common cases, this parma will not be stored in the database.

The question is: is there any security issue with this JSONP api?

If it has, how it be can used by a hacker?

XSS or CSRF?

Can somebody show me a use case here?

Answer (score 2):

The security issue of [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) is always on the client side (unless you allow such a request to store anything on your server, which you shouldn't) - you're executing more-or-less trusted foreign scripts on your page.

It basically is as insecure as `eval`. But if the attacker can utilize either of them, then **something else** is wrong (not the `eval` or JSONP in itself).